# Objective C / Autoresizing subviews not working

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, autoresizingmask

So, I'm trying to make a calendar from an image.

Images are in higher resolution then the screen, so I thought about loading the image to a larger view, adding everything to it (as subviews), resizing the view to fit the screen to show the user, then if he decides to save the image, resizing it again to a larger size and saving it. (It's mostly working as I intended).

The problem I'm having is the subviews I add to my ImageView won't resize.

Loading the image to my ImageView and enabling AutoresizesSubviews:

```
[self.backgroundImageView setImage:backgroundImage_];
[self.backgroundView setAutoresizesSubviews:YES];
```

Adding a UILabel on it:

```
UILabel *calendarLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(screenWidth_ * 0.1, 0, screenWidth_ * 0.8, screenHeight_ * 0.15)];
[calendarLabel setText:@"Calendar"];
[calendarLabel setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[calendarLabel setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
[calendarLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[self.backgroundImageView addSubview:calendarLabel];
```

Saving the size it should be resized to:

```
savedRect_ = self.backgroundView.frame;
```

Resizing the imageview (actually resizing the parent of the imageview, since imageView occupies the whole view):

```
[self.backgroundView setFrame:savedRect_];
```

Now I have no idea why this isn't working as I intended it.

PS: Did some testing and it turns out it's a little different with the programmatically added views then the ones added with IB. I have a feeling it has to do with AutoresizingMask.

Did some research, and I would imagine I have to make everything flexible (it can grow in width, height, size on top, bottom, right and left sides), but it's still isn't working. If I enable all the 6, the view just doesn't move.

**Could anyone tell me what setting I need to make so the views stay at the same position related to their parent View?**

Comment: Let me see I understand correctly what you want: you want your imageView, with a big image, to  have the frame of the whole screen, independent of the image's size?

Comment: Either I don't understand in right, or it's not what I want. I want a big view equal to the size of my image, create the calendar on it, then shrink that view (with it's subviews) to the size of the screen so they user can see it, and if he does, I increase it back to the original (large) size and save it as an image. (I have to do the shrinking and enlarging so it saves it at a better resolution).

Comment: Please show us the current and desired output. What are the sub views? Labels?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, turned out to be an easy solution as I expected...

I tried applying each mask separately:

```
[calendarLabel setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin];
[calendarLabel setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth];
....
```

Instead of:

```
[calendarLabel setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin];
```

Comment: Er, it's a bitmask, so every time you set it, all the bits are cleared or set.  It's not additive.  "Setting each mask separately" results in only the last command being effective.  One bit is set; the others are cleared.